# Chain two worker manager and start the second worker if the first succeed

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I searched about chaining worker managers. but I couldn't find a good example of chaining workers.

for example, they're talking about compressing the photo and then uploading it using chaining workers.

can anyone tell me how to do so? Like how to get the compressed image from copressionWorker (first worker) and pass it to the uploadWorker (second worker)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Google has released a [codelab for WorkManager](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0) that covers workers chaining.
This codelab should give you a good introduction on how to use WorkManager.

call `WorkManager.beginWith()`. This returns a [WorkContinuation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation), which defines a chain of [WorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest)s. You can add to this chain of work requests by calling `then()` method, for example, if you have three WorkRequest objects, workA, workB, and workC, you could do the following:

```
WorkContinuation continuation = mWorkManager.beginWith(workA);
continuation.then(workB) // then() returns a new WorkContinuation instance
            .then(workC)
            .enqueue(); // Enqueues the WorkContinuation which is a chain of work
```

Comment: How to handle error on middle of chain for example?

Comment: If a Worker returns `Result.failure()`, then that work and all dependent work is marked as `FAILED`. Same for cancellations/ Once a Worker is cancelled, all dependent work is cancelled as well.
Please take a look at the official documentation for additional information on how this works: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/chain-work#work-statuses

Comment: Thank you! I've already use `Result.success()` always with data on output